# problem with putting an element into a container

Tags: html, css

I want to put my progress bar in a container. but when I create the container for some reason the progress bar hides and only the container is visible?! 
what I'm missing?

Here is the working code without the container. (container is commented)

```css
/* I tried to create a container here
.containerProgress{
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 10.2vw;
  top: 54vh;
  height: 23vh;
  width: 29vw;
  outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;
}
*/

#progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0vw;
  height: 9.436435124508519vh;
  margin: 62.909567496723468vh 0vw 0vh  11.2119791666666659491vw;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red, red 2.80299479166666659491vw, orangered 2.80299479166666659491vw, orangered 5.60598958333333297455vw);
  border-radius: 18vh;
  box-shadow: inset 0vw 7.8636959370904332vh 1.40149739583333318982vw rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0vw 0.7863695937090432vh 0vw rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0vw -3.9318479685452166vh 0.42044921875vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0vw 2.3591087811271296vh 0.280299479166666681018vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  left: -0.70074869791666659491vw;
  top: -3.9vh;
  width: 2.5vw;
}

#progress-bar:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 16vh;
  background: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.7);
  border-radius: 18vh;
  content: "";  
  left: -0.70074869791666659491vw;
  top: -3.25vh;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerProgress"> 
<div id="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code a bit, and I think this `margin: 62.909567496723468vh 0vw 0vh  11.2119791666666659491vw;` is pushing your progress  bar out of view.

Try changing your `margin-top` and `margin-left` to 0.

Comment: np :) I would also reccomend using percentage, ems or rems instead of viewheight and viewwidth on regular basis. It can get tricky and/or messy with vh&vw. 
P.S. please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you had `margin: 62.909567496723468vh 0vw 0vh  11.2119791666666659491vw;` and `overflow: hidden` set on parent div, so it got pushed down to the point of not being visible.

```css
.containerProgress {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 10.2vw;
  top: 54vh;
  height: 23vh;
  width: 29vw;
  outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;
}


#progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0vw;
  height: 9.436435124508519vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red, red 2.80299479166666659491vw, orangered 2.80299479166666659491vw, orangered 5.60598958333333297455vw);
  border-radius: 18vh;
  box-shadow: inset 0vw 7.8636959370904332vh 1.40149739583333318982vw rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0vw 0.7863695937090432vh 0vw rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0vw -3.9318479685452166vh 0.42044921875vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0vw 2.3591087811271296vh 0.280299479166666681018vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 2.5vw;
}

#progress-bar:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 16vh;
  background: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.7);
  border-radius: 18vh;
  content: "";  
  left: -0.70074869791666659491vw;
  top: -3.25vh;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerProgress"> 
<div id="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```